# Format number in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to check if the data contains an alphabet. Upon searching, I found this code: `number($input) != number($input)`, it is working.

Can anyone explain to me the logic behind that? Thank you.

Comment: Please look up on the documentation of the `number()` function.

Answer (score 3):

If `$input` contains something other than a number (e.g. a letter),
[`number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-number) function returns `NaN`, in your case both calls to `number`
return `NaN`.

Two `NaN` values are not treated as equal, so in this case `NaN != NaN` is true.